# What's VS2010 shortcut for surrounding the line in a if block

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Let's assume I have a following line

```
myObject.SomeStatement();
```

My cursor is at the end of the line.
What's the keboard shortcut to put an if statement around it and obtain:

```
if ()
{
    myObject.SomeStatement();
}
```

What's the keboard shortcut to put a for loop around it and obtain:

```
for (int i = 0; i<length; ++i)
{
    myObject.SomeStatement();
}
```

Comment: You don't have a **ReSharper** tag assigned, so I guess you do not have ReSharper. But for those that have ReSharper: **Ctrl+E, Ctrl+U, Enter**. If you have nothing selected the whole line is surrounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use **Edit.SurroundWith** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and then select `if` from the popup list

You can surround with a `for` in a similar manner.

There are actually many surround templates available - I also use the `try` and `tryf` templates quite often (perhaps a sign that I'm doing it wrong ☺).

Answer (score 2):

In addition, please check also this reference page [Visual Studio 2010 Keybinding Posters](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13189), with details on shortcuts for all VS2010 languages.

Comment: I already did. I couldn't find the shortcut there, so I posted on SO. It's definitely good to have it, or better - learn it :)

Comment: The URL contains orange colored buttons to download PDF files with keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: I meant that I had downloaded the document before I posted on SO.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know the behaviour you want isn't quite there, but something close, i think. Take your statement:

```
myObject.SomeStatement();
```

and select the line, e.g. by double clicking, and press CTRL+K, CTRL+S, then select the "snippet" you want to apply.